# How to reuse a generic class without getting a compiler warning

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have the following domain model, which I simplified a little bit just for illustration purposes.

```
public abstract class JsonSerializer<T> {

    public abstract JsonElement toJsonElement(final T object, final Locale locale);

    public JsonArray toJsonArray(final Collection<T> objects, final Locale locale) {
        return objects.stream().map(t -> toJsonElement(t, locale)).collect(JsonArray::new, JsonArray::add, JsonArray::addAll);
    }
}

public class FruitJsonSerializer<T extends Fruit> implements JsonSerializer<T> {}

public abstract class Fruit {}

public class Banana extends Fruit {}

public class Apple extends Fruit {}
```

Then, when I want to serialize any fruit, I do:

```
FruitJsonSerializer serializer = new FruitJsonSerializer();
serializer.toJsonElement(new Banana());
serializer.toJsonElement(new Apple());
```

But I get a warning from the compiler saying that it is an unchecked call to "toJsonElement" as a member of raw type.

How can I avoid this warning without having one serializer declaration per implementation (`FruitJsonSerializer<Apple>`, `FruitJsonSerializer<Banana>`, etc)?

Comment: What about `JsonSerializer<Fruit>`?

Comment: It would not compile since toJsonElement would be expecting a collection of Fruit which is not compatible with a collection of , for example , bananas

Answer (score 2):

Generic parameter should be a concrete class, not a subset of classes. You can declare `JsonSerializer<Apple>` or `JsonSerializer<Banana>`. Without a parameter it considered as `JsonSerializer<Fruit>`.

If you do not want to make `FruitJsonSerializer` generic then shouldn't write `FruitJsonSerializer<T extends Fruit>` if. It is enough to inherit it from `JsonSerializer<Fruit>`. That's my variant:

```
public static interface JsonSerializer<T> {
    JsonElement toJsonElement(final T object);
    JsonArray toJsonArray(final Collection<? extends T> objects, Locale locale);
}

public static class FruitJsonSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Fruit> {}
```

Note that wildcard used for generic parameter of `Collection<? extends T>`.

Comment: Thanks for your time Zefick. But that would not compile. I will edit my question giving more details about the implementation of the JsonSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ? wildcard

```
FruitJsonSerializer<? super Fruit> serializer = new FruitJsonSerializer<>();
```

Edit: changed extends to super.

Comment: It won't compile when using toJsonArray since a List<Apple> is not compatibly with Collection<? super Fruit>

Answer (score 0):

Use generics for a class A if

- class A can handle multiple different object types with a base class or interface B,
- you want to limit the usability of some A instances to specific B subclasses.

E.g. `List` can handle all `Object` subclasses, and a `List<String>` gets limited to `String` elements by compiler type checking and thus saves you from some types of subtle bugs.

Your `JsonSerializer` is a valid example calling for generics. But I have my doubts about `FruitJsonSerializer`.

I suggest to remove the type parameter from FruitJsonSerializer:

```
public class FruitJsonSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Fruit> {}
```

Your examples imply that you plan to use the very same FruitJsonSerializer for any kind of Fruit, so there seems to be no need for a `FruitJsonSerializer <Apple>` or any other specialization.

Maybe I'm wrong, then leave the class definitions as they are, and construct your instances the correct way:

```
FruitJsonSerializer<Fruit> generalSerializer = new FruitJsonSerializer<>();
FruitJsonSerializer<Apple> applesSerializer = new FruitJsonSerializer<>();
```

The first one can be used for any `Fruit`, the second only for `Apples`.

One more remark: change the `toJsonArray()` method to read:

```
JsonArray toJsonArray(final Collection<? extends T> objects, final Locale);
```

Otherwise you won't be able to pass a `List<Apple>` to a `JsonSerializer<Fruit>`.